# Python's matplotlib legend in separate axis with gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Let suppose I have a matplotlib's gridspec instance in a python script. What I want to do is to create two axis and have the plot in one axis and the legend in the other one. Something like

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import gridspec, pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,100)
y = np.sin(x)

gs = gridspec.GridSpec( 100, 100 )
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[ :50, : ])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[ 55:, : ])
ax1.plot( s, y, label=r'sine' )
ax2.legend() # ?? Here I want legend of ax1
plt.show()
```

Is there any way of doing that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can grab the legend handles and labels from the first subplot using [`ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels), and then use them when you create the legend on the second subplot.

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels):

> `get_legend_handles_labels(legend_handler_map=None)`
>
> Return handles and labels for legend
>
> `ax.legend()` is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels() 
> ax.legend(h, l)
> ```

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import gridspec, pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure()

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(100, 100 )
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:50, :])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[55:, :])

ax1.plot(x, y, label=r'sine')

h, l = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels() # get labels and handles from ax1

ax2.legend(h, l)                       # use them to make legend on ax2

plt.show()
```

[image]